# Match columns pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to match two pandas Dataframes by the name of their columns.

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[0,2,1],[1,3,0],[0,4,0]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])


    A   B   C
0   0   2   1
1   1   3   0
2   0   4   0

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[0,0,1],[1,5,0],[0,7,0]], columns=['A', 'B', 'D'])

    A   B   D
0   0   0   1
1   1   5   0
2   0   7   0
```

If the names match, do nothing. (Keep the column of df2)

If a column is in Dataframe 1 but not in Dataframe 2, add the column in Dataframe 2 as a vector of zeros.

If a column is in Dataframe 2 but not in Dataframe 1, drop it.

The output should look like this:

```
    A   B   C
0   0   0   0
1   1   5   0
2   0   7   0
```

I know if I do:

```
df2 = df2[df1.columns]
```

I get:

```
KeyError: "['C'] not in index"
```

I could also add the vectors of zeros manually, but of course this is a toy example of a much longer dataset. Is there any smarter/pythonic way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears that `df2` columns should be the same as `df1` columns after this operation, as columns that are in `df1` and not `df2` should be added, while columns only in `df2` should be removed. We can simply [`reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) `df2` to match `df1` columns with a `fill_value=0` (this is the safe equivalent to `df2 = df2[df1.columns]` when adding new columns with a fill value):

```
df2 = df2.reindex(columns=df1.columns, fill_value=0)
```

`df2`:

```
   A  B  C
0  0  0  0
1  1  5  0
2  0  7  0
```